# How to render diagrams in gi-gtk?

Tags: haskell, gtk, gtk3, gtk2hs

I want to render a [diagram](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams) on top of a GUI written with [gi-gtk](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk). I tryed to use  the [`defaultRender`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-gtk-1.4/docs/Diagrams-Backend-Gtk.html#defaultRender) function from the `Diagrams.Backend.Gtk` but the compiler is complaining with :

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘gtk-0.15.5:Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types.DrawingArea’
              with actual type ‘Gtk.DrawingArea’
  NB: ‘Gtk.DrawingArea’
        is defined in ‘GI.Gtk.Objects.DrawingArea’
            in package ‘gi-gtk-3.0.36’
      ‘gtk-0.15.5:Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types.DrawingArea’
        is defined in ‘Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types’ in package ‘gtk-0.15.5’
• In the first argument of ‘defaultRender’, namely ‘canvas’
```

After verifying the `Diagrams.Backend.Gtk`, I saw that it is builded with the old `Graphics.UI.Gtk.Types` from GTk2Hs which seems the cause of this error.

**Is there a similar module as `Diagrams.Backend.Gtk` written with the [GI.Gtk](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk) package ?**

**Do you know if in the future the diagrams backend will be build with the [GI.Gtk](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gi-gtk) package ?**

Comment: The `diagrams-gtk` package is really [just about 100 LOC](https://github.com/diagrams/diagrams-gtk/blob/master/src/Diagrams/Backend/Gtk.hs) that would need to be ported. Perhaps it would make sense for you to do it and file a PR.

Comment: (Of course that's mainly because it's little more than a thin wrapper around `diagrams-cairo`; first it might make sense to just use that directly.)

Answer (score 1):

There is another package [diagrams-gi-gtk](https://github.com/tkemps/diagrams-gi-gtk) which probably contains what you are looking for.
I have recently updated it to GTK4, so you might want to use my fork until it gets merged.